# Error in restoring wazuh backup restoration in Ubuntu22

Tags: wazuh

I am trying to restore wazuh security events from backup. By default wazuh restores security events for only last 24 hours. I want to restore all the security events that i backed up.

I have unarchived all the files using command "nohup ./recovery.py -eps 500 -min 2023-06-10T00:00:00 -max 2024-01-25T23:59:59 -o /tmp/recovery.json -log ./recovery.log -sz 2.5 &".

This has created a recover.json file and a recovery.log file. I have set the location for he .json file in the "/usr/share/filebeat/module/wazuh/alerts/manifest.yml" file and restarted filebeat.

The recovery.json file has unarchived all the logs but the recovery.log file is empty.